# Report Server, Maximum request length exceeded

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report

При попытке залить .rdl отчет на сервер пишет "Maximum request length exceeded", вычитал якобы по дефолту стоит максимум 4мб, мой отчет 6мб, те отчеты, которые <= 4мб заливаются. Нашел вот эту [статью](http://www.isolutionspartners.com/sql-reporting-services-error-maximum-request-length-exceeded/), сделал не помогает. Прошу подсказать что делать.

Ошибка которую пишет сам сервер в логи :

```
    ui!ReportManager_0-2!360!03/07/2017-12:28:18:: e ERROR: System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-1!d4c!03/07/2017-12:28:18:: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
ui!ReportManager_0-2!360!03/07/2017-12:28:18:: e ERROR: HTTP status code --> 500
-------Details--------
System.Web.HttpException: Maximum request length exceeded.

   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()

   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetMultipartContent()

   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()

   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()

   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)

   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()

   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-1!764!03/07/2017-12:28:18:: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
ui!ReportManager_0-2!360!03/07/2017-12:28:18:: e ERROR: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg)
```

Версия :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
```

Comment: У вас отчёт скорее всего многостраничный. rdl поддерживает вложеные отчёты. Сделайте что б некоторые страницы отчёта были вложеными. Возможно это вам поможет. У меня все отчёты до полу-метра.

Comment: Ещё вариант - xml-ку rdl, если там большой % кирилицы, можно переделать на windows-1251 кодировку, это ужмёт в 2р русские надписи в utf-8. Как раз в 1,5 раза можно выиграть сжатие.

Comment: 3. Какая версия отчёта у вас? Новая версия содержит "разметку" которую можно удалить из ветвей. 4. Тексты sql-запросов можно заменить хранимками.

Comment: @nick_n_a страница в отчете одна, данных много. Можно по подробней чего то  я не понял этого 2-го коммента про windows-1251? Версия отчета? Имеется в виду версия репорт билдера в котором делал?

Comment: В статье значится "request length". "File length" и "request length" это разные вещи.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2005/01/reportdefinition"` вот это отчёт 2005 билдера. Старая версия отчёта меньше. Кодировка xml-ки (rdl-ки)  utf-8. Но никто не запрещает переконвертить xml в 1251.

Comment: У вас данных на 6 мегабайт??? Отчёт позволяет получить данные из базы и помещать их и в заголовки и куда угодно. Может вам длинные названия, текстовку хранить тогда в базе, а не в файле отчёта?

Comment: @nick_n_a версию отчета можно посмотреть выгрузив его уже сформированный или на стадии создания в репорт билдере? А где это поле находится File length? Ошибку пишет именно Maximum request length exceeded, но уменьшая файл(удаляя нужные поля) он заливается.

Comment: @nick_n_a переделал на хранимку, вес отчета не уменьшился ни на 1 кб.

Comment: Стоп, request length нужна что б передать/принять файл. Может вам это поможет http://www.aspnet.com.ua/BlogAll/ne-zagrujayutsya-bolshie-fayly-v-iis7.aspx/290#.WL6MNuZGSQg? Какой у вас IIS?

Comment: @nick_n_a спасибо! Помогла вот эта статья https://forums.iis.net/t/1199113.aspx?Maximum+request+length+exceeded , Там написано в принципе что и вы писали